# Hide "Decline to Sign" from DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

How to hide "Decline to Sign" feature from other actions in DocuSign envelope?
I'm using Java esign package. Also I couldn't find any option to turn it off in the web console.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there isn't a setting that allows you to remove the Decline to Sign Button in the DocuSign Web Application. However, You can hide its visibility.

To do that you need to set the DocuSign_DeclineAllow to False in the Signing Resource File, you can check how to do so, in this article:

https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301&bundleId=docusign-signing-resource-file-guide&topicId=docusign-signing-resource-file-guide.pdf&_LANG=enus